# When I click submit nothing echos out. Why?

Tags: php, html

I have some code.

This is my config.php

```
<?php

$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "hello_world_accounts";

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='. $db_name . ';charset=utf8', $db_user, $db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

This is my index.php

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['hello_world_accounts'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
}

if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION);
    header("Location: login.php");
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Welcome to index</p>


<a href="index.php?logout=true">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my jslogin.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
session_start();
require_once('config.php');


$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$emailval = ['email'];

$check = (strpos($emailval,'@'));

if ($check === false){
    echo 'We require valid email';
}else{

$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username=? and password=? and email=? LIMIT 1";
$stmtselect = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmtselect->execute([$username, $password, $email]);
$user = $stmtselect->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($stmtselect->rowCount() > 0) {
    $_SESSION['accounts'] = $user;
    echo 'You have signed in successfully!';
}else {
    echo 'Incorrect Username or Password or Email';
}
}
```

This is my login.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
    session_start();
    
if(isset($_SESSION['hello_world_accounts'])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Programming Knowledge Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
        <div class="user_card">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="brand_logo_container">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" class="brand_logo" alt="Programming Knowledge logo">
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">
                <form>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><em class="fas fa-user"></em></span>                 
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input_user" placeholder="Username" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><em class="fas fa-key"></em></span>                  
                        </div>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input_pass" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-1">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><em class="fas fa-inbox"></em></span>                    
                        </div>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input_pass" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlInline">Remember me</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-1 login_container">
                <button type="button" name="button" id="login" class="btn login_btn">Login</button> 
            </div>
            </form>
            <div class="mt-3 mb-1">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
                    Don't have an account? <a href="registration.php" class="ml-2">Sign Up</a>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#login').click(function(e){

            var valid = this.form.checkValidity();

            if(valid){
                var username = $('#username').val();
                var password = $('#password').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
            }

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'jslogin.php',
                data:  {username: username, password: password, email: email},
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    if($.trim(data) === "1"){
                        setTimeout(' window.location.href =  "index.php"', 1000);
                    }
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert('There were errors while doing the operation.');
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

No matter what I enter it doesn't say anything.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yhbw.png)

It doesn't say anything when I click submit if you look in the image. Until this is fixed I will comment this out.

Did I do something wrong?

I looked at tutorials and questions on SOF and I even looked at the manuel.

Comment: AND Please dont store **plain text passwords** to your database. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: Well you have to validate the inputs - _HINT_ First check they actually exist.  So look at the [PHP String Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) section of the PHP manual for something that meets your needs. In the process you will learn 20 other useful things

Comment: For future reference, please post error mesages as text and not pictures.

Comment: Is this academic code purely for learning, or for a production site? There's a huge difference in approach used.

Comment: I assume these messages come from `alert(data);` in the AJAX success handler. After fixing the undefined array key notices, you should write server side validation (client side is a nice touch for the user, but shouldn't be relied upon) and return a fitting error message.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried to do that and i won't let me copy paste it

Comment: @RiggsFolly Also they do exist if you look in my code. In mysql they are there.

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is a localhost I will use password_hash() later on

Comment: If you are learning, then its more efficient to learn the Good Practices NOW not later. Why waste time learning bad habits, you may never break

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, My question is if I can stop the error message from popping up and make my own customized error saying "Please use correct credentials" whenever the input is not written the right way.

Comment: And by _Check they exist_ I mean check the POST parameters have actually been passed for example `if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {` checks that the page was activated by a POST and not just by someone hacking about and finding this script, then `if ( isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email'];) ) {` checks that the required params were actually filled

Comment: Ok. Thank you. That actually helps. Where would you put that code though?

Comment: I refer you back to mysecond comment! Look through the manual for an appropriate string manipulation function that will check if an `@` exists in the email, and any other validation you want to do

Comment: That code, right at the top of the script

Comment: Ok so I think I got progress. I still don't know how to stop the error from popping up but I know how to create one when that happens

Comment: @RiggsFolly So the config.php or what?

Comment: I fixed it. thanks for your help

Comment: What have you tried to fix this? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase php problem

Comment: Then please remove the JS tag, and add your debugging attempts to the question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase done

Comment: `if(valid){
                var username = $('#username').val();
                var password = $('#password').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
            }` 

You are defining the variables inside an if block......... that is wrong.

Comment: im not defining the variables that statement is if the variable username is equal to the variable id username

Answer (score 0):

You declare your variables inside of an if block. So what is happening is when the code is running it is sending up the DOM references to the server, not the values of the elements you reference.

You are submitting the form when it is not valid. You need to exit.

So add check for invalid, and exit, remove the variables from the if.

```
    $('#login').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var valid = this.form.checkValidity();
        if(!valid){
            alert('Error');
            return;
        }

        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        $.ajax({...});
    }
```

Comment: I will try this